# Using IP address and splitting in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, split, ip-address

HELP! I'm stupid stuck and can't find how to do this. 
Also because I am a beginner in Python.

I need help with this script in Python.

1. How can I used an IP address in a python script?
2. How can I split an IP address based on a dash (-)

I am trying to do this

```
#code
a = input("Enter ip address: ")
print 'edit "ip-' + str(a) + '"\n',

# Shell

Enter ip address:10.203.1.10
# output
edit "ip-10.203.1.10"
```

How can a IP address be stored? When I add the decimal points I can get an error
Is there a module or package or some secret. Can the split method work like this
x.split("-") to split and IP address how do you store the values then (a,b)? to have
something like this.

## input

`10.228.50.88-10.228.50.91`

## output

edit "ipr-10.228.50.88-10.228.50.91"

set type iprange

set start-ip 10.228.50.88

set end-ip 10.228.50.91

Really appreaciate any help or anyone that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: where do u want to store the ip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below script will help you:

```
a = raw_input("Enter ip address: ")

print 'edit "ip-' + str(a) + '"\n'

if '-' in a:
    ips = a.split('-')

    print ('set type iprange')

    print ('set start-ip '+ips[0])
    print 'set end-ip '+ips[1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Added this split!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `input` while running this on Python 2. You expect its return type to be a string, but it's not. In Python 2, `input` actually tries to *parse and execute the input as if it was Python code*. Obviously, `192.168.0.0`, or any IP address, is invalid Python code, so you get an error.

To solve this, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Then, `a` would be of type `str`, that is, a regular string (there's nothing special about IP addresses), so you can use `a.split`, `a.join` and other methods of the `str` class.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input, input is doing this: `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.  The eval means it is trying to take the input and interpret it as python code, which is why you are getting syntax errors.  It also says: Consider using the [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function for general input from users, which sounds like what you are looking for.  Also, a quick test and from the Python3 doc, it looks like the input() functionality is different and behaves more like the raw_input() function.  Quick tests:

Python 3.6.2:

```
>>> a = input("Enter ip address: ")
Enter ip address: 10.1.1.1
>>> a
'10.1.1.1'
```

Python Python 2.7.13:

```
>>> a = input("Enter ip address: ")
Enter ip address: 10.1.1.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    10.1.1.1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```